# How to get following sibling attribute?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

So I'm going through exercises in an XML workbook and I need to be able to get the following sibling of a given element in a collection of all those elements in the document. In the following for example I need to get the set of all `NODE2` elements in the entire document and from that I need to select the `NODE2` element with a position of 1 and a first following sibling with `'attrib'` attribute equal to `$var`...

```
<ROOT>
  <SUBROOT>
     <NODE1>
        <NODE2 attrib="data1">
        <NODE2 attrib="data2">
     </NODE1>
     <NODE1>
        <NODE2 attrib="data3">
        <NODE2 attrib="data4">
     </NODE1>
     <NODE1>
        <NODE2 attrib="data5">
        <NODE2 attrib="data6">
     </NODE1>
   </SUBROOT>
</ROOT>
```

This is what I have so far but it isn't working. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
<xsl:value-of select=".//NODE2[following-sibling::@name[1]=$var and position()=1]" 
 />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of all `NODE2` elements is `descendent-or-self::NODE2` or `//NODE2`. You don't need that "`.`"

There is no following sibling which is an attribute (`name`), as you wrote in your code. There can be a following sibling which is a `NODE2`, so you can write `following-sibling:node()` or `following-sibling:NODE2` (since all sibling nodes are `NODE2` anyway).

Now that you have that `following-sibling`, you can add a predicate to test for its attribute. Not `name`, but `attrib` (according to your code). You can use either `attribute::attrib` or `@attrib`. Then it could be `@attrib = $var` in a predicate.

You can connect the second predicate with an and or with another pair of brackets, since they don't change the context. It could be `[pred1 and pred2]` or `[pred1][pred2]`. So you can say `element[1][@attrib=$var]` or `element[position() = 1 and @attrib = $var]`.

I think that should get you in the right direction.